# How Do I Shorten Python Code By Getting Rid of Var=0

Tags: python

I'm currently having a competition with my friends to create the shortest solution (in lines) to a python problem.

I figure there must be a way to get rid of the `total=0` in this for loop

```
total=0
for x in word:
    total += x
print total
```

(I am aware that I can put the for loop all on one line)
To clarify I am going to be using the variable further

Comment: use the built-in [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) function?

Comment: You should describe the *actual* problem you're trying to solve, what is `word`

Answer (score 5):

You can't in this context, but you don't even need that loop:

```
sum(list_of_ints)
```

Comment: my mistake i over simplified the problem

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only concerned about the number of lines, you could check if `total` has been declared already:

```
for x in word:
    total = x if 'total' not in locals() else total + x
print total
```